# gzinflate in Java

Tags: java, php, interop, zlib

So, my Java application reveives some data that is generated with PHP's gzdeflate().
Now i'm trying to inflate that data with Java. This is what i've got so far:

```
InflaterInputStream inflInstream = new InflaterInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(inputData.getBytes() ), new Inflater());

byte bytes[] = new byte[1024];
while (true) {
    int length = inflInstream.read(bytes, 0, 1024);
    if (length == -1)  break;

    System.out.write(bytes, 0, length);
}
```

'inputData' is a String containing the deflated data.

The problem is: the .read method throws an exception:

> java.util.zip.ZipException: incorrect header check

Other websites on this subject only go as far as redirecting me to the Inflater class' documentation, but apparently I don't know how to use it to be compatible with PHP.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Per the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzdeflate.php), php gzdeflate() generates raw deflate data (RFC 1951), but Java's [Inflater class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/zip/Inflater.html) is expecting zlib (RFC 1950) data, which is raw deflate data wrapped in zlib header and trailer.  *Unless* you specify [nowrap as true](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/zip/Inflater.html#Inflater%28boolean%29) to the Inflater constructor.  Then it will decode raw deflate data.

```
InputStream inflInstream = new InflaterInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(inputData.getBytes()), 
                                                   new Inflater(true));

byte bytes[] = new byte[1024];
while (true) {
    int length = inflInstream.read(bytes, 0, 1024);
    if (length == -1)  break;

    System.out.write(bytes, 0, length);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the GZIPInputStream as per examples at (do not use the Inflater directly):

http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/compression/

Comment: That doesn't work
I now have changed the first line to InputStream inflInstream = new GZIPInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream( inputData.getBytes() ));
Which results in java.util.zip.ZipException: Not in GZIP format.

Comment: Save the data into a file and open it using some ZIP tool, and validate the format ...